Why is the input bar spilling slightly on the right side of the container?
I made a calculator using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Everything is working fine but the input bar is slightly overflowing on the right side.
I tried aligning it to center and so many things, but nothing worked.

Here is my code (only the input part):


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  outline: 5px solid gray;
}
.container input {
  width: 100%;
  border-style: none;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  outline: 2px solid;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
    <div class="container">
      <!--Input-->
      <div class="input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Write your equation here  " value="" />
      </div>



How can I get the input to fit within the container?

Please don't fill your question with nonsense to overcome the build in rules of posting on [SO]. Check [ask].

Please do not fill your post with repeated or nonsense content as a way to work around the quality filter. If the system prompts you to add additional explanation to your post, then do so. Don't attempt to bypass the warning. This is considered an abuse of the system, and may lead to your post being summarily removed and/or your account being sanctioned. Take the [tour], read up on [ask] and then [edit] your post with more details.

The input container doesn't quite overflow anything given the code in your question.

@KIKOSoftware I included a picture of the issue at the beginning in case I was not able to adequately explain it.

if an element is not defined as box-sizing: border-box the width is not calculated with the padding. meaning it calculates 100% width and added 10px from the padding-right: 10px


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* the change */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  outline: 5px solid gray;
}

.container input {
  width: 100%;
  border-style: none;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  outline: 2px solid;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
<div class="container">
  <!--Input-->
  <div class="input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Write equation here" value="" />
  </div>



